# Highlight text in a PDF document viewer

Tags: winforms, text, highlight, axacropdf

I have a WinForms application and am using AxAcroPDF COM component to display PDF files in my application. I want to highlight occurrences of some text in the PDF document using the AxAcroPDF component. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

just since there are no answers here - according to [Adobe's API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/interapplication_communication.html) there is a method SetCurrentHighlight, which hightlights text within the specified rectangle (I haven't tried this):

> **SetCurrentHighlight**
>
> Highlights the text selection within the specified bounding rectangle
>   on the current page.
>
> **Syntax** void setCurrentHighlight(LONG nLeft, LONG nTop, LONG nRight,
>   LONG nBottom);

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way is there, you may like to do all kind of text editing features using [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/company/press.php?id=408). It is now available for major platforms like linux, Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Mendeley (https://www.mendeley.com/) does the work like a charm!

In fact, Mendeley is more than a PDF-reader. You can use it to organize your docs and references .

[image: mendeley does the job]